Symmetrically scale object along profile on a single axis
I'm quite new to blender, trying to make a 3d printable dog a little bit more anatomic and want to shrink a bit area in front of back legs. Maybe this picture describes best what I'm trying to achieve (top view).

Spent several hours an best what did achieved is to use Curve modifier and Radius to curve points. Radius affects all axises and I need only to scale in Y axis. Also tried to play with geometry nodes but with no success at all.
Also tried to separate that area and scale it. Looks rough.

Any hints would be highly appriciated!
UPD
@josh-sanfelici suggested proportional editing and it gave pretty good result. I also did bisect to get a straight edge loop. The only downside is that it is irreversible transformation.


The only thing I could suggest would be the same as @joshsanfelici did. Especially having no idea how you created your model (it looks like a very messy, not symmetrical and in no way structured mesh) and I have no idea how you expected the Curve modifier to work in this case...

Select the mesh, go to edit mode, Alt click on an edge to select one entire edgeloop, enable Proportional editing on top center of the window, press S, Y, move the mouse and scroll the middle wheel to trim the effect, when satisfied confirm with left click (in my example I used Z axis instead of Y).


Good option, thank you! I will try. But this looks like irreversible transformation. Is there any kind of parametric way to ease the process of fine-tuning and also preserving ability to work on initial model?

You can do it on a shape key, so to have a parametric control of the deformation, and preserve the Basis shape.
